# Why does Spring not always use batch insert/update when configured?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my Spring JpaRepository based project, I have a method that always loads records one by one from the method that calls saveAll(List list)...when I use a List where I create the objects and add them to the list. Below code takes about 5 minutes...

---

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public List<Data> saveAll(List<Data> dataList) throws Exception {
 try {
        for(Data d : dataList){

            if(d.getCol04() == null)
                d.setCol04("TEST");
            else
                d.setCol04(null);

            log.info(new Gson().toJson(d));

        }

        return dataRepository.saveAll(dataList);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unexpected error.", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

> 2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
>     2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[
>      com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=866, batchId=6012113450}]
>      2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for
>   [com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=866,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity
>   [com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=866,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Done entity load
>       2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Loading entity: [com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=867,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:11 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
>           select
>               datae0_.batch_seq as batch_seq1_0_0_,
>               datae0_.batch_id as batch_id2_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col01 as col3_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col02 as col4_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col03 as col5_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col04 as col6_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col05 as col7_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col06 as col8_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col07 as col9_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col08 as col10_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col09 as col11_0_0_,
>               datae0_.col10 as col12_0_0_,
>               datae0_.group_id as group_id13_0_0_,
>               datae0_.parent_trans_id as parent_trans_id14_0_0_,
>               datae0_.result_message as result_message15_0_0_,
>               datae0_.result_status as result_status16_0_0_,
>               datae0_.tn as tn17_0_0_,
>               datae0_.tn_quantity_assigned as tn_quantity_assig18_0_0_,
>               datae0_.tn_quantity_requested as tn_quantity_reque19_0_0_,
>               datae0_.xml_data as xml_data20_0_0_ 
>           from
>               owner.batch_data datae0_ 
>           where
>               datae0_.batch_seq=? 
>               and datae0_.batch_id=?
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=867,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for
>   [com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=867,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity
>   [com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=867,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Done entity load
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Loading entity: [com.test.Data#component[batchSeq,batchId]{batchSeq=868,
>   batchId=6012113450}]
>       2019-10-30 09:07:12 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
>       .
>       .
>       .
>       2019-10-30 09:10:34 DEBUG o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - Reusing batch statement
>       2019-10-30 09:10:34 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
>           update
>               owner.batch_data 
>           set
>               col01=?,
>               col02=?,
>               col03=?,
>               col04=?,
>               col05=?,
>               col06=?,
>               col07=?,
>               col08=?,
>               col09=?,
>               col10=?,
>               group_id=?,
>               parent_trans_id=?,
>               result_message=?,
>               result_status=?,
>               tn=?,
>               tn_quantity_assigned=?,
>               tn_quantity_requested=?,
>               xml_data=? 
>           where
>               batch_seq=? 
>               and batch_id=?
>       2019-10-30 09:10:34 DEBUG o.h.e.j.batch.internal.BatchingBatch - Executing batch size: 500
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(2081270212)] after
>   transaction
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
>           77841799 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
>           0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
>           89273975 nanoseconds spent preparing 1501 JDBC statements;
>           250886005163 nanoseconds spent executing 1500 JDBC statements;
>           4812997147 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC batches;
>           0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
>           0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
>           0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
>           5462588455 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1500 entities and 0 collections);
>           0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
>       }
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.h.e.j.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1953492703)] for JPA
>   transaction
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Setting JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@113673215 wrapping
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5f71a000] read-only
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation,
>   JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
>       2019-10-30 09:10:36 DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin

SaveAll(List list) loads in batches when I query findAll(List id) and use the returned list as the argument to saveAll. Below code takes about 8 seconds.

---

```
//Working method

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public List<Data> saveAll() throws Exception {

    try {
        List<Data> dataList2 = dataRepository.findAllByBatchId(6000000L);

        for(Data d : dataList2){

            if(d.getCol04() == null)
                d.setCol04("TEST");
            else
                d.setCol04(null);

            log.info(new Gson().toJson(d));

        }

        return dataRepository.saveAll(dataList2);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unexpected error.", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

> .
>       .
>       .
>       2019-10-30 09:00:25 DEBUG o.h.e.j.batch.internal.BatchingBatch - Executing batch size: 500
>       2019-10-30 09:00:27 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(2038854767)] after
>   transaction
>       2019-10-30 09:00:27 INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
>           89300419 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
>           0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
>           1037028 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
>           330435552 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
>           6423148647 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC batches;
>           0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
>           0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
>           0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
>           7100764566 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1500 entities and 0 collections);
>           2082345 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
>       }
>       2019-10-30 09:00:27 DEBUG o.h.e.j.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
>       2019-10-30 09:00:27 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json]
>       2019-10-30 09:00:27 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing ["{"data":0}"]
>       2019-10-30 09:00:27 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA
>   EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining what the actual question is?

Comment: Using basically the same method, one takes 8 seconds and uses a batch update and the other takes 5 minutes and updates records one by one.
The only difference is that in the slow update, I pass in a list of objects that I built in the code, whereas in the faster method, i query the list from the database.

Comment: They both use the batch update `saveAll()`?

Comment: They both use saveAll(List<Data> list).
The Spring method signature is <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities).

The one that runs fast generates far less logging when i have stats turned on.

Comment: neither of these methods update records one by one... they each call the repositories `saveAll()` method....

Comment: Whatever queries you are running before you call `saveAll(List<Data> dataList)` to get the data is probably what is slowing you down so much... you're loading records one at a time? That would probably be it

Comment: That was my understanding also. The log suggests the same, but one is significantly longer. I thought that maybe Spring is calling the save() method, withing saveAll, on each record in the list. 
I also turned logging off and the performance is the same. The only difference is how the object instance. One comes directly from the database Select query response and the other is built from within my code.

Comment: How many records are you reading one by one? Log the time it takes to load all the records one by one

Comment: Are you having the same amount of records both times? Could be 5M records for first and 5K for second

Comment: Rob...You may be correct. I am going to run a few tests after changing this method.
dataRepository.findAllByIdIn(idList);

Comment: Xtreme...the record count is always the same (1500)

Comment: I guess the problem is that in the first case (the 5 minute case) the list comes out of the transaction context (you do not show us that but that's educated guess) and if so then hibernate needs to load those data from rdbms afresh as it does not know how the data in rdbms look like. It also looks like - you do not show us that either - that Data type is quite complex entity and loading it is expensive. In the second case you load the data in the same transaction context and therefore hibernate knows the data, it does not need to reload them afresh.

Comment: As for my last comment, long story made short: please make sure the same @Transactional is around both data reading and writing and tell us if that made a difference.

Comment: Actually, I see I say the same as @sandeep pandey, except that I also add 'make sure you have one transactional context (i.e., @Transactional).

Comment: Verifying and trying the @Transactional suggestions now...

Comment: Working as expected now! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be because of dirty checking feature, In first method when you are saving dataList before saving the data, hibernate might be loading all data in memory to check which data has been modified.This could be reason why it takes time and If Data(entity) is further associated with other entity then this add up on time. Where as in second method as dataList2 is preloaded before saving to database, hence no resolution is done at the time of saving. In order to test this theory you may eager load all data(along with associated entity) and then save, if it takes same time as equal to second method, then we might conclude this.  Please also refer this link https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=994162&view=previous, it might help

Comment: Working as expected now!